# Uncaught TypeError: $.fn.snd_slider.external_move_to is not a function

Tags: javascript, jquery, wordpress, function, scope

I'm in the process of creating a wordpress theme but keep on encountering the error mentioned in the title. For the last couple days I've been trying to figure out why the function is not being seen but can't seem to find a solution.

In the front-page.php.  I have the following function call in a click event for a marker in google maps.

```
$.fn.snd_slider.external_move_to( marker_order );
```

which function is located in my main.js file. I apologize for the length of code but I thought it was necessary to include more in case I overlooked something:

```
(function($){
    $.fn.snd_slider = function( options ) {
        var settings = $.extend( {
            slide                   : '.snd-slide',                 // slide class
            arrows                  : '.snd-slider-arrows',         // arrows container class
            prev_arrow              : '.snd-arrow-prev',            // left arrow class
            next_arrow              : '.snd-arrow-next',            // right arrow class
            controls                : '.snd-controllers a',         // control selector
            control_active_class    : 'snd-active-control',         // active control class name
            previous_text           : 'Previous',                   // previous arrow text
            next_text               : 'Next',                       // next arrow text
            fade_speed              : 500,                          // fade effect speed
            use_arrows              : true,                         // use arrows?
            use_controls            : true,                         // use controls?
            manual_arrows           : '',                           // html code for custom arrows
            append_controls_to      : '',                           // controls are appended to the slider element by default, here you can specify the element it should append to
            controls_class          : 'snd-controllers',            // controls container class name
            slideshow               : false,                        // automattic animation?
            slideshow_speed         : 7000,                         // automattic animation speed
            on_slide_changing       : function(){},                 // callback function that runs when a slide changes
            on_slide_change_end     : function(){}                  // callback function that runs when a slide changes
        }, options );

        return this.each( function() {
            var $snd_slider         = $(this),
                $snd_slide          = $snd_slider.find( settings.slide ),
                snd_slides_number   = $snd_slide.length,
                snd_fade_speed      = settings.fade_speed,
                snd_active_slide    = 0,
                $snd_slider_arrows,
                $snd_slider_prev,
                $snd_slider_next,
                $snd_slider_controls,
                snd_slider_timer,
                controls_html = '';

            if ( settings.use_arrows && snd_slides_number > 1 ) {
                if ( settings.manual_arrows == '' )
                    $snd_slider.append( '<div class="snd-slider-arrows"><a class="snd-arrow-prev" href="#">' + settings.previous_text + '</a><a class="snd-arrow-next" href="#">' + settings.next_text + '</a></div>' );    
                else
                    $snd_slider.append( settings.manual_arrows );

                $snd_slider_arrows  = $( settings.arrows );
                $snd_slider_prev    = $snd_slider_arrows.find( settings.prev_arrow );
                $snd_slider_next    = $snd_slider_arrows.find( settings.next_arrow );

                $snd_slider_next.click( function(){
                    snd_slider_move_to( 'next' );

                    return false;
                } );

                $snd_slider_prev.click( function(){
                    snd_slider_move_to( 'previous' );

                    return false;
                } );
            }

            if ( settings.use_controls && snd_slides_number > 1 ) {
                for ( var i = 1; i <= snd_slides_number; i++ ) {
                    controls_html += '<a href="#"' + ( i == 1 ? ' class="' + settings.control_active_class + '"' : '' ) + '>' + i + '</a>';
                }

                controls_html =
                    '<div class="' + settings.controls_class + '">' +
                        controls_html +
                    '</div>';

                if ( settings.append_controls_to == '' )
                    $snd_slider.append( controls_html );
                else
                    $( settings.append_controls_to ).append( controls_html );

                $snd_slider_controls    = $snd_slider.find( settings.controls ),

                $snd_slider_controls.click( function(){
                    snd_slider_move_to( $(this).index() );

                    return false;
                } );
            }

            snd_slider_auto_rotate();

            function snd__slider_auto_rotate(){
                if ( settings.slideshow && snd_slides_number > 1 ) {
                    snd_slider_timer = setTimeout( function() {
                        snd_slider_move_to( 'next' );
                    }, settings.slideshow_speed );
                }
            }

            function snd_slider_move_to( direction ) {
                var $active_slide = $snd_slide.eq( snd_active_slide ),
                    $next_slide;


                if ( direction == 'next' || direction == 'previous' ){

                    if ( direction == 'next' ){
                        console.log(snd_slides_number);
                        snd_active_slide = ( snd_active_slide + 1 ) < snd_slides_number ? snd_active_slide + 1 : 0;
                    }

                    else
                    {
                        snd_active_slide = ( snd_active_slide - 1 ) >= 0 ? snd_active_slide - 1 : snd_slides_number - 1;
                    }

                } else {

                    if ( snd_active_slide == direction ) return;

                    snd_active_slide = direction;

                }

                $next_slide = $snd_slide.eq( snd_active_slide );

                if ( settings.use_controls && snd_slides_number > 1 )
                    $snd_slider_controls.removeClass( settings.control_active_class ).eq( snd_active_slide ).addClass( settings.control_active_class );

                if ( settings.on_slide_changing )
                    settings.on_slide_changing( $next_slide );

                $active_slide.animate( { opacity : 0 }, snd_fade_speed, function(){
                    $(this).css('display', 'none');

                    $next_slide.css( { 'display' : 'block', opacity : 0 } ).animate( { opacity : 1 }, snd_fade_speed, function(){
                        if ( settings.on_slide_change_end )
                            settings.on_slide_change_end( $next_slide );
                    } );
                } );

                if ( typeof snd_slider_timer != 'undefined' ) {
                    clearInterval( snd_slider_timer );
                    snd_slider_auto_rotate();
                }
            }
            isitafunction = function(number){
                console.log(number);
            };
            $.fn.snd_slider.external_move_to = function( slide ) {
                snd_slider_move_to( slide );
            }
        } );
    }



})(jQuery)
```

Any help would be much appreciated!

Comment: Check if you js files are loaded correctly

Comment: Jorge, thanks. Yes, I did that by creating a test global function outside of $.fn.snd_slider and successfully called it from the php file.

Comment: Try to add the function inside documet.ready or outside

Comment: Thanks Jorge, but no luck with that.

Answer (score 0):

I discovered the answer to my question. It's slightly embarrassing, but I realized that I wasn't making a call to the function which returned the function I was trying to access. Mistakes are for learning from, right?